# query CSV file, table name with period

Tags: sql, vba, csv, qtp, hp-uft

I made a function to query a CSV file. It all works just fine... but, when a header contains a period it generates an error. (This is in UFT/QTP).

```
'Create ADODB connection object
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


'Create Recordsetobject
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Provider  = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
objConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strCSVpath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
objConnection.Open

'Execute the query
objRecordSet.open sqlQuery, objConnection 

value = objRecordSet.fields.item(0)                 

objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close
Set objConnection = Nothing
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
```

The CSV contains something like:

```
head1;head2;hea.d3;
val1;val2;val3;
```

Reading header 3 (hea.d3) gives an error. 
Tried:

```
"Select hea.d3  from [test.csv] "
"Select [hea.d3]  from [test.csv] "
"Select (hea.d3)  from [test.csv] "
```

Non works... can anyone give me advice?

Cheers, 
Giel

Comment: what does select * reveal?

Comment: With a select * I see in the recordset that the header is named "hea#d3". I also do see a value....

Comment: Then Try Select hea#d3  from [test.csv]

Comment: Nop, doesn't work... I get an error it has the wrong format.

Comment: What does work: select [hea#d3] from [test.csv] 
Thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
select [hea#d3] from [test.csv]
```

thanks.